# separate event function trigger twice on a child element where parent has the same event function

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is my snippet, the issue is, if you click unto the "li" element that has a text of "test 1" the alert prompt did trigger once (normal) but if you click unto the "li" element that has a text of "test 2", the alert prompt triggered twice like the click event function called twice. Any ideas, clues?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on("click", ".nav a", function(){
    
   alert("test"); 
  })
  $(document).on("click", ".dp a", function(){
    
   alert("test"); 
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
    <ul class="dp">
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because for the `<li>`s with "test 2", both `.nav a` and `.dp a` will match, hence both handlers would be invoked

Comment: can you post your answer please with a fiddle?

Comment: Why registering 2 handlers in the first place? Your first handler would run just fine for all descendants `<a>` elements

Comment: im creating a custom dropdown menu.

Comment: a custom dropdown menu where if they click unto a dropdown container (the second ul that has a class of dp) then hide the dropdown menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), It will prevent any parent event action

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".nav a", function() {
    alert("test");
  }).on("click", ".dp a", function(e) {
    e.stopPropogation();
    alert("test");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
    <ul class="dp">
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE :**

As haim770's suggested, bind event handler to the appropriate selector to prevent bubbling

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".nav > li > a", function() {
    alert("test");
  }).on("click", ".dp a", function() {
    alert("test");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">test 1</a>
    <ul class="dp">
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's an artificial solution. A better approach would be to register the correct handler with the correct selector

Comment: I don't think the OP realized that the first handler would match all descendants `<a>` elements. That's also why I didn't post my own answer, I need to understand what is he trying to achieve and why registering 2 handlers in the first place (didn't downvote though).

Comment: Well, according to the last comment by the OP, I think your second solution would work.

Comment: @haim770 : let's wait for his response

Comment: great. work like charm! TY, Mr. Pranav. anyway, im trying to make a custom dropdown menu where there will be a scenario that when a user click unto any of the dropdown (e.g the second ul inside a child li "dropdown container ul"), the dropdown container should be hidden so that why i bind two handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Specify which hyperlink for the first click event.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/Loc4427u/1/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on("click", "ul:nth-child(1) > li > a", function(){

   alert("test"); 
  })
  $(document).on("click", ".dp a", function(){

   alert("test 2"); 
  })

});
```